Firebase Authentication Error: SMS Verification Code Request Failed (Error Code: 17499, Error Code: 39)
Issue Description
I'm encountering an issue with Firebase Authentication, specifically when trying to request SMS verification codes for user authentication. The request fails, and I receive the following error logs:
Environment:

Firebase SDK Version: (firebase_auth: ^5.1.4)
Authentication Method: SMS-based Authentication
Tools/IDE: (e.g., Android Studio, VSCode, etc.)

Steps to Reproduce:

Set up Firebase Authentication in the project with the required dependencies.
Attempt to sign in via SMS verification using FirebaseAuth.
The SMS request fails, showing the errors above in the logs.

What I Have Tried:

Verified the Firebase configuration and ensured that the Google Services JSON is correctly placed in the app.
Checked the permissions in the Android Manifest (i.e., internet, receive SMS).
Enabled the SMS Retriever API in the project.
Reinstalled the app, cleaned project, and synchronized Gradle.

However, the error persists.
Error Codes:
From my research:

Error code 17499 seems to be a generic internal error, but no specific solution is provided.
Error code 39 is not well-documented in Firebase docs or support.

My Question:

What does the error code 17499 and 39 mean in this context?
Are there specific settings in Firebase Console or on the client-side (Android) that I might be missing or misconfiguring?
Is this an issue with Firebase's services (perhaps a region-specific limitation or temporary issue)?

Any insights or guidance on resolving this would be greatly appreciated!

Additional Information:

Firebase Documentation: Firebase Auth Documentation


@RakeshRebbavarapu Thank for reply, i'm on blaze plan
